# Do there exist open-source tools to process and aggregate DMARC and MTA-STS reports?

Tags: dns, email

Both DMARC and MTA-STS provide email addresses for 3rd parties to send delivery reports in XML or JSON formats.

Are there any FOSS tools that process and aggregate these reports?  There are 3rd party SaaS providers for things like this, but would like a FOSS if available.

- DMARC reports [look like this](https://mxtoolbox.com/dmarc/details/what-do-dmarc-reports-look-like)
- MTA-STS the report format is in [Section 4.4 of the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8460.txt)

Comment: It's unclear what the input looks like, what's being aggregated, and what the output should look like. There are _many_ open-source tools for processing XML and JSON documents in various ways.

Comment: @Kusalananda, these are standard formats.  I added links for your reference.  As for output format, any aggregate format (preferably with a web interface) would be acceptable.